# Audio Speech Recognition Speech2Text. Solucionar RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.models.speech_to_text.feature_extraction_speech_to_text

Tags: python, jupyter, audio, validationerror, encoding

estoy haciendo un proyecto para mi TFM. Os pongo un poco en contexto: lo que pretendo hacer es utilizar varios modelos de Automatic Speech Recognition (transformar audio a texto) con transformers. El trabajo está hecho con Python. Pretendo utilizar tres tipos de modelo: Speech2Text, Wac2Vec y UniSpeech.

Los dos últimos modelos (Wac2Vec y UniSpeech) funcionan correctamente. El Speech2Text funcionaba hasta la semana pasada. Hoy me ha empezado a dar problemas. Al correr el código me salta el siguiente mensaje: **"No se encuentra el punto de entrada del procedimiento en la biblioteca e vínculos dinámico"**. Además, el error que aparece en python es el siguiente: **"RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.models.speech_to_text.feature_extraction_speech_to_text because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
[WinError 127] No se encontró el proceso especificado"**

Alguien podría ayudarme a resolver esto?

Os adjunto el código

```
#Librerias
import librosa
import torch
from transformers import Speech2TextProcessor, Speech2TextForConditionalGeneration
import IPython.display as display
from evaluate import load
import soundfile as sf
from transformers import Wav2Vec2ForCTC, Wav2Vec2Tokenizer

#Importo audio
speech, rate= librosa.load("audio_tipo2_1.wav", sr=16000)
display.Audio ("audio_tipo2_1.wav")


#Modelo speech to text
model = Speech2TextForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("facebook/s2t-small-librispeech-asr")
processor = Speech2TextProcessor.from_pretrained("facebook/s2t-small-librispeech-asr")
inputs = processor(speech, sampling_rate=16000, return_tensors="pt")
generated_ids = model.generate(inputs["input_features"], attention_mask=inputs["attention_mask"])
transcription = processor.batch_decode(generated_ids, skip_special_tokens=True)
print(transcription)
```